# IBM jre javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError

Tags: java, log4j

I'm trying use log4j with IBM JRE,

While configuring DOMConfigurator with log4j file like the following,

```
DOMConfigurator.configure(log4jfileAbsPath);
```

I get the following error. With Sun jre it is working fine.

```
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:694)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:604)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.java:733)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be in rt.jar, but it seems that IBM doesn't have it there. You have to find xercesImpl-**version**.jar and put it in a classpath. You should discover which **version** is right for you.